# Remove duplicate results by using awk

Tags: awk, conditional-associations

I have a given library list and it is required to find them in specific folders and give an abstract report.

What i did:

1. I put the libraries into a file, each lib is in a row
2. I read each line(lib) by using readline in while loop
3. Checked them by using find command and filtered by using awk

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
   do find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -type f -name $line | awk -v pattern=$line -F/ '{print $1"\t"pattern"\t\t"$4}';
   done < libList
```

Liblist is like

```
libA
libB
libC
.
.
```

result is like the following
however first 4 results are actually same
as i dont want to consider existance of libs in some subfolders.

How could I display those duplicate ones only once?
How could I sort the results by first DIRs then Lib name then Example?

I know this  `'!_[$0]++'` eliminates duplicates but not in my case
I think need to condition those like A[$1$4]++ something but can't really work it out and how to put pattern there A[$1$2]B[pattern]++?

```
**DIR3  libA    example1
DIR3    libA    example1
DIR3    libA    example1
DIR3    libA    example1**
DIR3    libB    example2
DIR3    libB    example2
DIR3    libB    example1
DIR3    libB    example1
DIR3    libB    example1
DIR3    libB    example1
DIR2    libC    example3
DIR2    libC    example3
DIR3    libC    example3
DIR3    libC    example3
DIR3    libC    example2
DIR3    libC    example2
DIR3    libC    example1
DIR3    libC    example1
DIR3    libC    example1
DIR3    libC    example1
DIR1    libD    example2
DIR1    libD    example2
DIR3    libD    example2
DIR3    libD    example2
DIR3    libD    example1
DIR3    libD    example1
DIR2    libE    example4
DIR2    libE    example4
DIR2    libC    example3
DIR2    libC    example3
```

Comment: If they're already sorted, add `|uniq`, otherwise add `|sort|uniq` :-P

Comment: I know about uniw but when I add "uniq" in tail of awk the all results are distorted a funny way. I remember there was a way to do it like  if ( !_A[$1$4] );print...    grouping the fields and creating a grouped condition any idea?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and use uniq on that? Also in which way are the results "distorted"?

Comment: I think I should get rid of all while loop and run awk command calling system inside awk, now while loop passing one line by each iteration so awk cant do comparision..

Comment: Yea Chatterone it came into my mind and then it will give reqult I tried it thanks, I didnt one to create another file and would prefer to solve everything on the go but its ok as it gives what i want.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -type f -name "$line"
done < libList |
awk -F'/' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $NF, "", $4}' |
sort -u
```

but without seeing a few lines of sample output from `find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -type f -name "$line"` it's a guess.

You could use

```
awk -F'/' -v OFS='\t' '{val=$1 OFS $NF OFS OFS $4} !seen[val]++{print val}'
```

instead of the above `awk '...' | sort -u` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Ed, sort worked there in first suggestion and also the second solution is very good I just made a small change there by using "printf("%-40s %-40s %s\n" to have neat results. I have neer seen "!seen" term before was very good to find out about it

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
   do find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -type f -name $line | awk -v pattern=$line -F/ '{print $1"\t"pattern"\t\t"$4}';
   done < libList > result_file

cat result_file | uniq| sort
```

will provide what i need
thanks

Answer (score 0):

After applying Ed's suggestion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
do find DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 -type f -name "$line";
done < libList | 
awk -F'/' '{val=$1$NF$4} !seen[val]++{printf("%-40s %-40s %s\n", $NF,$1,$4)}'
```